# Jqgrid edit function show html code

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

i have this code to change cell value color

```
function highlight(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
       var color = (parseInt(cellValue) < 10000) ? "red" : "green";
      var cellHtml = "<span style='color:" + color + "' originalValue='" + cellValue + "'>" + cellValue + "</span>";       

       return cellHtml;
    }
```

but when i try to edit data
the html code is show in form input

[image]

what i must to do,so the html code not show in input form

Answer (score 0):

In short: You have to change that input's style, while you are just adding code to the input's value right now.

You can define the id or class(es) for the input in your css, and use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) / [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) or [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) from jquery.

Or you can just change your input's style properties directly from jquery:

```
$('input.myClass').css('background-color', color);
```